# Convergence of the improper integral $\int _{1}^{\infty}{\frac{x}{1-e^{x}}dx}$

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

Need help determining  the convergence/divergence of the  following improper integral:

$$\int \limits_{1}^{\infty}{\frac{x}{1-e^{x}}dx}$$

I tried using comparison tests but with no luck.

Comment: Linear term in the top, an e-power in the bottom, well.....If you use taylor expansion of the e-power, what are the first couple of terms?

Comment: @imranfat, the first few terms are not going to help, as the problem is at $\infty$...

Comment: Can you tell us what you tried? With what did you try to compare? This integral is **so** convergent that it is difficult to come up with a comparison which does not work! :-)

Comment: The denominator is growing exponentially while the numerator grows linearly, as $x\to\infty$.  That's most of the answer. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez The first 4 would do, wouldn't it? A linear divided by a cubic? Easy...

Comment: @imranfat That reasoning would imply $\int_1^\infty \frac{x}{\sin x}\; dx$ is convergent (there, you also have a linear divided by a cubic).  I think you could argue that any Taylor polynomial for $1-e^x$ overestimates (i.e. is not as negative as) the function itself, though.

Comment: Point well taken. It works for the e-power because all terms are positive so one can make a comparison with the e-power. It does not work with the sine because it's alternating. I should have observed that more carefully

Comment: In general, $$\int_0^\infty\frac{x^n}{e^x-1}~dx ~=~ n!~\zeta(n+1),$$ for $n>0$, and $$\int_0^\infty\frac{x^n}{e^x+1}~dx ~=~ n!~\eta(n+1),$$ for $n>-1$. See the [Riemann $\zeta$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) and [Dirichlet $\eta$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function) function for more information.

Answer (score 2):

For sufficiently large $x$, $e^x-1>x^3$. So there exists a constant $C\ge1$ such that 
$$
\int_C^\infty\frac x{e^x-1}dx<\int_C^\infty\frac1{x^2}dx<\infty.
$$
So your integral also converges.

Answer (score 1):

We can enforce the substitution $x\to \log x$ to reveal that

$$\begin{align}
\int_1^{\infty}\frac{x}{e^x-1}\,dx&=\int_e^{\infty}\frac{\log x}{x(x-1)}\,dx\\\\
&\le \int_e^{\infty}\frac{\log x}{(x-1)^2}\,dx\\\\
&=\lim_{L\to \infty}\left.\left(\frac{(1-x)\log|1-x|+x\log |x|}{1-x}\right)\right|_{e}^{L}\\\\
&=-\log(e-1)+\frac{e}{e-1}\\\\
&<\infty
\end{align}$$

Therefore, the integral converges!

Comment: I feel like this would be clearer if you made the substitution $x = \log u$ to make it clearer what is happening. Good solution though.

Comment: @brevanellefsen Thank you for the nice compliment!  Much appreciative.